# Finding the Inverse of a 5th-Order Polynomial Function

Tags: inverse

Find the inverse of: $F(x)=7x^5-5x^3-3x^2+2x$.

Comment: One does not invert equations. You can invert a function, though. Incidentally, this seems awfully difficult since the function is a 5th order polynomial.

Comment: Just wrap your equation in dollar signs, and *voilà*

Comment: Thank you and I meant equation, I always seem to get those 2 words mixed around. I tried inversing it myself and could not get the correct function.

Comment: It is very unlikely that you were explicitly asked to do this. Perhaps you were asked to do something else $E$, and you knew that if you could find an explicit general formula for the inverse, you could do $E$. If one knew what $E$ was, perhaps one could suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: What you are after is a solution to the equation $7x^5-5x^3-3x^2+2x-c=0$. This always has 5 solutions, but this particular function is not factorizable.

Comment: Please add why you want $f^{-1}$ ? Maybe there is any other approach to it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are given is a *function* $F(x)$, not an *equation*.

Start with $F(x) = y = 7x^5 - 5x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x$.

Exchange $x$ and $y$:

$x = 7y^5 - 5y^3 - 3y^2 + 2y= y(7y^4 - 5 y^2 - 3y + 2)$ and "solve" for $y$ to express it in terms of $x$, but rename $y$ as $y^*$ to avoid confusion with the rest of the description of the most frequent technique for finding the inverse of a function, in general.

(In this case, this will not be terribly easy, algebraically!)

Then $F^{-1}(x) = y^*$

---

I just saw your comment: is this the approach you tried?

Comment: I will go and attempt doing the problem again and I may come back with a migraine.

Comment: This reminds me of the old internet joke. Step 1: Write down $F(x)$. Step 2: Exchange $x,y$. Step 3: ???? Step 4: Profit!!!

Comment: @Christopher hahahahaha...I like that! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

$f(x),x,f^{-1}(x)$ in same plot. Maybe this can help  if you want to see behavior of curves or find number of intersections.

Comment: $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are mirror images about mirror $x=y$

Answer (score 0):

If you use Mathematica, here's what I'd do:

Make a table of small increments

mytable = Table[{ f [x] , x } , {x, 0, 10, 0.01} ]

Then you can plot this and get a visual representation of the inverse.
If you want the analytical inverse, just use the Fit function on this table to get a polynomial like this:

myfit = Fit[mytable, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]

This will at least get you a polynomial function that is the inverse, though it won't be the true inverse, just an approximation.